# Write a class that is generic over a type parameter of type `std::size_t A` and is only able to increment its `A` by 'consuming' i.e. `std::move` it

Tags: c++

I want to write a C++ class with such a definition:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t A = 0>
struct Counter {
    static constexpr inline std::size_t valueOfA = A;

    T value;
};
```

I want to have a member function `addOne()`, such that it consumes itself, e.g. `Counter<0>` and returns itself but of a type where its type parameter is the sum of 1 and its previous type argument, e.g. `Counter<1>`. Simply put, `Counter<1> Counter<0>.addOne()`.

`addOne()` should also consume itself such that all variables referencing to `Counter<A>` should not be valid variables after `addOne()` is called.

[GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ax3aG5188)

The compiler error I got this:

```
x86-64 clang 15.0.0
x86-64 clang 15.0.0
-std=c++2a
123
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x86-64 clang 15.0.0 - 1285ms
<source>:32:16: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'Counter<[...], 0>' to function return type 'Counter<[...], 0UL + 1 aka 1>'
        return *this;
```

**EDIT:** Some have asked for 1. a minimal reproducible example and 2. a reason for wanting to do something like that.

1. Minimal Reproducible Example (in fact, I am giving the full concrete example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t A>
struct AddOne {
    static constexpr inline std::size_t value = A + 1;
};

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
struct IsALesserThanB : std::integral_constant<bool, A < B> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t MEC, std::size_t EC = 0>
class Secret {
private:
    T value;

    template <std::size_t NewEC=AddOne<EC>::value>
    constexpr inline Secret(
        Secret<T, MEC, EC>&& this_secret) {
        T value_ = std::move(this_secret.value);
        return Secret {
            .value = value_,
        };
    }

public:

    Secret(T initialValue) : value(std::move(initialValue)) {}

    template <
        typename Closure,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<
            std::is_invocable<Closure, const T&>, IsALesserThanB<EC, MEC>>>>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline std::tuple<
        std::invoke_result_t<Closure, const T&>, Secret<T, MEC, EC + 1>>
    exposeSecret(Closure closure) const noexcept {
        Secret<T, MEC, EC + 1> new_secret{std::move(*this)};
        return {closure(value), new_secret};
    }
};


int main() {
    Secret<double, 3, 2> secretString{std::move(69.69)};

    auto length =
        secretString.exposeSecret([](const double& s) { return "69"; });

    std::cout << std::get<0>(length) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

2. The Reason
   I want to create a type `Secret<T, MEC, EC>` in C++, such that whenever `expose_secret()` is called more than `MEC` times, it can no longer be called and the program cannot compile.

`expose_secret()` should also consume `Secret<T, MEC, EC>` (MEC: maximum exposed count, EC: exposed count) with each invocation of `expose_secret()` with `std::move`.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] inline in your question!

Comment: Suppose you [got your example to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/jr4v16odh) - what output do you expect from it?  Since you print `counter.valueOfA` before and after, it appears you expect it to change - but it can't possibly change, it's `constexpr`.

Comment: I find this whole idea bizarre.  What's the point of it?

Comment: _returns itself but of a type where its type parameter is the sum of 1 ..._ -- you cannot change the type of an oject at runtime. You ca only construct a new object of a different type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah, but `valueOfA` remains at 0, I want it to increase to 1, then 2 and so on whenever `addOne` is called. Anyway, `addOne` should also return a `Counter<A+1>` value.

Comment: @PaulSanders It is meant to be a compile-time counter, like to count at compile time how many times the `addOne` member function is called and if it exceeds a certain number, a compile error is raised.

Comment: @PaulSanders, updated my post with a more concrete example and an explanation of why I am doing this.

Comment: Compile-time counters [are possible](https://mc-deltat.github.io/articles/stateful-metaprogramming-cpp20)

Answer (score 0):

Well, stripping this down to the bare essentials, the solution is easy enough:

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t A = 0>
struct Counter {

    auto AddOne ()
    {
        static_assert (A < 100, "A is >= 100");
        assert (valid);
        valid = false;
        return Counter <A + 1> { };
    };

private:
    bool valid = true;
};

int main ()
{
    Counter c0;
    auto c1 = c0.AddOne ();             // static_assert ok here

    Counter <100> c100;
    auto c101 = c100.AddOne ();         // static_assert fails here
}
```

But I don't see this as being particularly useful, because each time `AddOne()` is called, it returns an object with a new type, so you can't keep track of how many times `AddOne()` has been called using just a single object.

If you drop the requirement for a compile-time check, this problem can be avoided.

Comment: Hi @paul, thank you for your response. Would you mind showing if Counter holds an inner value then how would you go about moving that inner value from `Counter<A>` to `Counter<A+1>`?

Comment: I would copy it (in `AddOne`), to the object that is about to be returned.  No need to move it, unless it is a type that defines a move assignment operator, in which case moving it would be more efficient than copying.